# How to loop through polygons and apply conditional statements in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, r, polygon, buffer

I am trying to perform calculations on polygon attributes that are based on counts within buffers and conditional statements and for loops. I am trying to decide if it is worth it to try working through this problem in QGIS, or if this would be unnecessarily difficult, and would be much more suited to R or python. While I would think this is a job for R or python, I find the part where buffers overlap to be something I would need to actually visualize in QGIS, vs just a dataframe where it would be difficult to envision.

Here is my problem:

I have 2 separate polygons layers, Polygons_A and Polygons_B

Each polygon within Polygons_A has assigned to it:

1. a "Burden" value
2. a "Capacity" value
   Such that my Polygons_A layer attribute table looks like:

```
ID    Burden      Capacity
-----------------------------
1         22            66
2         42            76
3         33            71  
4         24            45
5         57            83
...
```

Then I want to draw 1-mile radius buffers around each polygon, where I expect there will be lots of overlap between the buffers.
So now, each polygon has a 1-mile radius buffer assigned to it. Now, for each polygon in Polygons_A, I want to find how many polygons from Polygons_B fall within its buffer. (If the buffer boundary intersects a polygon, that polygon is still counted as within the buffer here) I then want to assign this count value to each polygon in Polygons_A, under a column called "Count", and so my Polygons_A attribute table would then look like:

```
ID    Burden      Capacity       Count_B
-----------------------------------------
1         22            66             3
2         42            76             4
3         33            71            11  
4         24            45            21
5         57            83             9 
...
```

Now, I want to take all the polygons from Polygons_A that fall within the buffer for each polygon from Polygons_A, and sum their "Capacity" values to create a "Surrounding capacity" value to be assigned to each polygon. This "Surrounding capacity" sum will exclude the "Capacity" value of the polygon the buffer is drawn around.
And thus the Polygons_A attribute table will now look like:

```
ID    Burden      Capacity      Count_B     Surrounding_capacity
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1         22            66            3                      336
2         42            76            4                      221
3         33            71           11                       68
4         24            45           21                      124
5         57            83            9                       56
...
```

Now, for each polygon from Polygons_A, I want to determine whether the "Burden" exceeds the "Surrounding capacity". And so I want to append a new column to the Polygons_A attribute table called "Exceeded", where values are determined by the following condition:
If, for each polygon in Polygons_A, the "Burden" exceeds the "Capacity", return "Count_B". If the "Burden" does not exceed the "Capacity", return 0.
And so my Polygons_A attribute table would now look like this:

```
ID    Burden      Capacity      Count_B     Surrounding_capacity    Exceeded
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         22            66            3                       19           3   
2         42            76            4                       38           4
3         33            71           11                       41           0
4         24            45           21                       39           0
5         57            83            9                       52           9
...
```

And then of course, I would want to convert this dataframe into a shapefile.

And finally, here is a visual representation of my problem over my map boundary (grey):

[image]

Where:
Yellow, Orange, and Red polygons all belong to "Polygons_A"

Blue polygons belong to "Polygons_B"

In this visual example, we can see that the buffer is drawn around a specific polygon from "Polygons_A", the red polygon. The orange polygons represent the all polygons from Polygons_A that fall within the buffer of the red polygon. And the blue polygons represent the polygons from "Polygons_B"

In the visual example, the "Exceeded" value would only be calculated for the red polygon, and so just for that row. Of course, an "Exceeded" value will need to be calculated for ALL polygon's in "Polygons_A", since every polygon from "Polygons_A" will get their own buffer. THIS complication that looks like a for loop is why I am thinking this is too complex for QGIS.

Can this be done with QGIS tools? Or would this better be done in Python or R? I like that I can visualize the data itself in QGIS, but once I get to conditional statements and for loops, I feel that would be difficult in QGIS. Or is there a much more concise way to carry this out in R or python?

Comment: Please decide about the approach: QGIS, Python or R

Comment: I will go with Python.

Comment: @LostinSpatialAnalysis perhaps you can tackle your problems step by step starting with the first which is "draw a buffer around polygons A and intersect with polygon layer B" - so basically you want to loop over polygons A for each polygon in that set you create a buffer around its centroid and then intersect with your b polygons. First things first, do you already have your polygon layers as shapely objects loaded and are ready to start writing the logic?